# Table tr and td have weird click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-click-event

I have a table like the following snippet shows.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.table-price td.go-to-price').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-link'));
    goToLink($(this).attr('data-link'));
  })

  $('.table-price tr.go-to-product').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-link'));
    goToLink($(this).attr('data-link'));
  })
})


function goToLink(url) {
  location.href = url ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-price">
  <tr class="go-to-product" data-link="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10013</td>
      <td>عنوان</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>
          <p class="">0</p>
      </td>
      <td class="go-to-price" data-link="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url#price-change" >
          <a href="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url#price-change">IMAGE</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `tr` has a `data-link` attribute and the last `td` has a different `data-link` attribute, but when I click on the `tr` element, the website navigates to url of `td` element, instead of the `tr` element.

Comment: use event stopPropagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the `click` event from bubbling when you click on the `td` using **[`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)**, like :

```
$('.table-price td.go-to-price').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();

  console.log($(this).attr('data-link'));
  goToLink($(this).attr('data-link'));
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.table-price td.go-to-price').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      
      console.log($(this).attr('data-link'));
      goToLink($(this).attr('data-link'));
  })

  $('.table-price tr.go-to-product').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();

      console.log($(this).attr('data-link'));
      goToLink($(this).attr('data-link'));
  })
})


function goToLink(url) {
  location.href = url ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-price">
  <tr class="go-to-product" data-link="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10013</td>
      <td>عنوان</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>
          <p class="">0</p>
      </td>
      <td class="go-to-price" data-link="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url#price-change" >
          <a href="http://tahrircenter.com/product/correction-pens/url#price-change">IMAGE</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please comment `location.href = url ;` so we could see what's `console.log()` showing..

Comment: I comment `location.href = url ;` and removed `href` from `a` ;